# Using Haproxy as TCP frontend to Nginx (SSL), OpenVPN and OpenSSH. Timing out, no connection

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, haproxy, tcp

I'm trying to configure Haproxy to run on public port 443 and send TCP traffic to the right place as follow:

- 2 Nginx instances with SSL termination. Traffic router to either depending of hostname. All web traffic is over HTTPS.
- OpenVPN
- OpenSSH

I think my config is pretty close, but somehow I can't get it to work. My web requests just timeout.

What am I doing wrong?

```
global
  log /dev/log  local0 debug # TURN OFF DEBUG!
  log /dev/log  local1 notice
  #log loghost   local0 info
  maxconn 1024

defaults
  log   global
  mode  http
  option   httplog
  option   dontlognull
  option   tcplog
  retries  3
  option redispatch
  maxconn  2000
  timeout connect  5000
  timeout client  50000
  timeout server  50000

listen HAProxy-Statistics
  bind *:1936
  mode http
  option httplog
  option httpclose
  stats enable
  stats uri /
  stats refresh 10s
  stats show-node
  stats show-legends
  stats show-desc Haproxy Frontend
  stats auth admin:admin

frontend ssl_relay
  bind 0.0.0.0:443 name frontend-ssl
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  option socket-stats
  # option nolinger
  maxconn  300
  log /dev/log local0 debug # overkill! turn this off when not needed

  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

  use_backend https_one if  { req_ssl_sni -i home.example.com }
  use_backend https_two if  { req_ssl_sni -i nc.example.com }
  use_backend openvpn   if !{ req.len 0 }
  use_backend openssh   if  { req.len 0 }
  default_backend https_one

backend https_one
  mode tcp
  server home-https-server 10.0.0.4:4443 send-proxy

backend https_two
  mode tcp
  server nc-https-server 10.0.0.4:4444 send-proxy

backend openvpn
    mode tcp
    server openvpn-server 10.0.0.4:1194

backend openssh
    mode tcp
    server openssh-server 10.0.0.5:22
```

Comment: What do your haproxy debug logs say? Does the openVPN and ssh part work?

Comment: Where are the requests timing out? Can HA Proxy reach the web servers?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the logs, but I can see the request coming in in the stats panel, but not reaching a backed. The browser tells me the request times out.

Comment: If logging is actually working, but you get nothing logged, that's going to be outside of, and before, HAProxy -- firewalls, iptables.  Verify logging and backend selection with a connection from inside the proxy: `$ true | openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername <sni-hostname> -showcerts` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about OpenVPN, I came to the conclusion that putting it behind is counterproductive.

1. You won't have a permanent session and if the backend dies and you were connected to that backend, you still need to reconnect.
2. OpenVPN comes with an easy to use load-balancing/failover option (I am not sure if it even reconnects automatically when one server fails):

```
remote server1.mydomain
remote server2.mydomain
remote server3.mydomain
remote-random
```

3. HAProxy forces you to use TCP instead of UDP, which means that you do packet hand-shakes twice: for the tunnel, and for the package encapsulated in the tunnel.

Comment: OpenVPN failover and some balancing also could be done by putting several A records under the single name, which is specified in the connecton profile (`remote`). Coupled with `resolv-retry infinite` this will make a client to try randomly chosen record each time, retaining the possibility to have ordered connection profile blocks in the client config (e.g. for the logic like "udp, than tcp as a fallback")